# Vue js error: Component template should contain exactly one root element

Tags: javascript, node.js, laravel, vue.js

I don't know what the error is, so far I am testing through console log to check for changes after selecting a file (for uploading).

When I run `$ npm run watch`, i get the following error:

> "Webpack is watching the files…
>
> 95% emitting
>
> ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors
>   19:42:29
>
> error  in ./resources/assets/js/components/File.vue
>
> (Emitted value instead of an instance of Error)    Vue template syntax
>   error:
>
> Component template should contain exactly one root element. If you
>   are using v-if on multiple elements, use v-else-if to chain them
>   instead.
>
> @ ./resources/assets/js/components/AvatarUpload.vue 5:2-181  @
>   ./resources/assets/js/app.js  @ multi ./resources/assets/js/app.js
>   ./resources/assets/sass/app.scss"

My File.vue is

```
<template>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="avatar" class="control-label">Avatar</label>
            <input type="file" v-on:change="fileChange" id="avatar">
            <div class="help-block">
                Help block here updated 4  ...
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="hidden" name="avatar_id">
            <img class="avatar" title="Current avatar">
        </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default{
        methods: {
            fileChange(){
                console.log('Test of file input change')
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Any ideas on how to solve this? What is actually the error?

Comment: You can also get this error if your </template> is misspelled. Happened to a friend of mine...

Answer (score 243, accepted):

**Note** This answer only applies to version 2.x of Vue. [Version 3 has lifted this restriction](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/new/fragments.html#overview).

You have two root elements in your template.

```
<div class="form-group">
  ...
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
  ...
</div>
```

And you need one.

```
<div>
    <div class="form-group">
      ...
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
      ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Essentially [in Vue you *must* have only one root element in your templates](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#A-Single-Root-Element).

Comment: This restriction is going away in Vue 3 fwiw. I can't find a source for this right now unfortunately, but they announced it at VueConf 2020.

Comment: Here's a source for Vue 3 : 
https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/class-and-style.html#with-components

Comment: Lol, I spent two days underneath to understand the illogical. Thank you guy.

Answer (score 25):

For a more complete answer: http://www.compulsivecoders.com/tech/vuejs-component-template-should-contain-exactly-one-root-element/

But basically:

- Currently, a VueJS template can contain only one root element (because of rendering issue)
- In cases you really need to have two root elements because HTML structure does not allow you to create a wrapping parent element, you can use [vue-fragment](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-fragment).

To install it:

```
npm install vue-fragment
```

To use it:

```
import Fragment from 'vue-fragment';
Vue.use(Fragment.Plugin);

// or

import { Plugin } from 'vue-fragment';
Vue.use(Plugin);
```

Then, in your component:

```
<template>
  <fragment>
    <tr class="hola">
      ...
    </tr>
    <tr class="hello">
      ...
    </tr>
  </fragment>
</template>
```

Comment: IMHO I have 2 arguments against v-fragment : 1) it's a unecessary dependency as you achieve the goal vith built-in fonctionnal componant 2) it breaks the "component approach". Both arguments came together, rejecting one may make v-fragment looks usefull I guess.

Comment: I totally agree with you. But there are specific cases (keep HTML structure right) where you need to use Fragment or Functional Components.

Comment: Looks like there's two repos "vue-fragment" https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-fragment and "vue-fragments" https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-fragments with different versioning

Answer (score 21):

You need to wrap all the html into one single element.

```
<template>
   <div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="avatar" class="control-label">Avatar</label>
            <input type="file" v-on:change="fileChange" id="avatar">
            <div class="help-block">
                Help block here updated 4  ...
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="hidden" name="avatar_id">
            <img class="avatar" title="Current avatar">
        </div>
   </div>

</template>

<script>
    export default{
        methods: {
            fileChange(){
                console.log('Test of file input change')
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: not work in table tr element .

Answer (score 8):

if, for any reasons, you don't want to add a wrapper (in my first case it was for `<tr/>` components), you can use a functionnal component.

Instead of having a single `components/MyCompo.vue` you will have few files in a `components/MyCompo` folder :

- `components/MyCompo/index.js`
- `components/MyCompo/File.vue`
- `components/MyCompo/Avatar.vue`

With this structure, the way you call your component won't change.

`components/MyCompo/index.js` file content :

```
import File from './File';
import Avatar from './Avatar';   

const commonSort=(a,b)=>b-a;

export default {
  functional: true,
  name: 'MyCompo',
  props: [ 'someProp', 'plopProp' ],
  render(createElement, context) {
    return [
        createElement( File, { props: Object.assign({light: true, sort: commonSort},context.props) } ),
        createElement( Avatar, { props: Object.assign({light: false, sort: commonSort},context.props) } )
    ]; 
  }
};
```

And if you have some function or data used in both templates, passed them as properties and that's it !

I let you imagine building list of components and so much features with this pattern.

Comment: Hi is there any other way where in i can prevent that root div from showing up after the template is rendered ?

Comment: Shortly the answer is : no.


But you can always do whatever you whant through the DOM api.


You should not play with the DOM generated by the template it leads to unsynchronization with the virtual DOm (or the things that act as).
As a consequence of changing the dom generated by the template you may have the template generated again thus you will have your template generated twice.

Answer (score 7):

Component template should contain exactly one root element. If you are using v-if on multiple elements, use v-else-if to chain them instead.

The right approach is

```
<template>
  <div> <!-- The root -->
    <p></p> 
    <p></p>
  </div>
</template>
```

The wrong approach

```
<template> <!-- No root Element -->
    <p></p> 
    <p></p>
</template>
```

**Multi Root Components**

The way around to that problem is using functional components, they are components where you have to pass no reactive data means component will not be watching for any data changes as well as not updating it self when something in parent component changes.

As this is a work around it comes with a price, functional components don't have any life cycle hooks passed to it, they are instance less as well you cannot refer to `this` anymore and everything is passed with context.

Here is how you can create a simple functional component.

```
Vue.component('my-component', {
    // you must set functional as true
  functional: true,
  // Props are optional
  props: {
    // ...
  },
  // To compensate for the lack of an instance,
  // we are now provided a 2nd context argument.
  render: function (createElement, context) {
    // ...
  }
})
```

Now that we have covered functional components in some detail lets cover how to create multi root components, for that I am gonna present you with a generic example.

```
<template>
 <ul>
     <NavBarRoutes :routes="persistentNavRoutes"/>
     <NavBarRoutes v-if="loggedIn" :routes="loggedInNavRoutes" />
     <NavBarRoutes v-else :routes="loggedOutNavRoutes" />
 </ul>
</template>
```

Now if we take a look at NavBarRoutes template

```
<template>
 <li
 v-for="route in routes"
 :key="route.name"
 >
 <router-link :to="route">
 {{ route.title }}
 </router-link>
 </li>
</template>
```

We cant do some thing like this we will be violating single root component restriction

**Solution**
Make this component functional and use render

```
{
functional: true,
render(h, { props }) {
 return props.routes.map(route =>
  <li key={route.name}>
    <router-link to={route}>
      {route.title}
    </router-link>
  </li>
 )
}
```

Here you have it you have created a multi root component, Happy coding

Reference for more details visit: https://blog.carbonteq.com/vuejs-create-multi-root-components/

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Bert and blobmaster responses:

If you need to remove the root element from the DOM you can exploit css and use [`display: value`](https://css-tricks.com/get-ready-for-display-contents/) on the root element.

Answer (score 2):

Bit of a misleading error.

What fixed it on my side was the fact that I had an additional `</div>` without an opening `<div>`.

I spotted it using Find/Replace on "div" which gave an odd number.

Comment: if you omitted the opening <div>, then the error is on point since you dont have a unique root element.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap everything in one div and it will resolve the issue. 
For example,

div

----div

----/div>

----div>

----/div>

/div

It is similar concept to React.js

Answer (score 2):

I experienced this kind of issue and the issue was fixed by adding a main parent `div` tag or `section` if it is a section type of component.

```
<div class="list-of-friends">
     <h3>Hello World</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

For vue 3 they removed this constraint in template syntax :

```
<template>
  <header>...</header>
  <main v-bind="$attrs">...</main>
  <footer>...</footer>
</template>
```

but it's still existing in JSX syntax :

**Incorrect  ❌**

```
setup(props,{attrs}) {

return ()=>(
     <header>...</header>
     <main  {..attrs}>...</main>
     <footer>...</footer>
)
}
```

**Correct ✔**

```
setup(props,{attrs}) {

return ()=>(
   <>
     <header>...</header>
     <main  {..attrs}>...</main>
     <footer>...</footer>
   </>
)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was confused as I knew VueJS should only contain 1 root element and yet I was still getting this same "*template syntax error Component template should contain exactly one root element...*" error on an extremely simple component. Turns out I had just mispelled </template> as </tempate> and that was giving me this same error in a few files I copied and pasted. In summary, check your syntax for any mispellings in your component.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using this

```
Vue.component('tabs', {
    template: `
        <div class="tabs">
          <ul>
            <li class="is-active"><a>Pictures</a></li>
            <li><a>Music</a></li>
            <li><a>Videos</a></li>
            <li><a>Documents</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="tabs-content">
          <slot></slot>
        </div>
    `,
});
```

you should use

```
Vue.component('tabs', {
    template: `
      <div>
        <div class="tabs">
          <ul>
            <li class="is-active"><a>Pictures</a></li>
            <li><a>Music</a></li>
            <li><a>Videos</a></li>
            <li><a>Documents</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="tabs-content">
          <slot></slot>
        </div>
      </div>
    `,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that you have one root div and put everything inside this root

```
  <div class="root">
    <!--and put all child here --!>
   <div class='child1'></div>
   <div class='child2'></div>
  </div>
```

and so on