# Vue component renders only the first element in the template DOM

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a Vue component inside a Vue loop on my website. Here's the JS file:

```
Vue.component('fb-question-text', {
  props: ['question'],
  template:
    '<label>Prompt</label><input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="question.prompt"><a href="javascript:void" class="fb-remove">Remove</a>'
});

var questionList = new Vue({
  el: '#questions',
  data: {
    questions: [
      {
        type: 'text',
        id: 'question1',
        prompt: ''
      },
      {
        type: 'choice',
        id: 'question2',
        prompt: '',
        choices: ['', '']
      }
    ]
  }
});
```

This is what my HTML file looks like:

```
<ul id="questions">
    <li v-for="(question, index) in questions">
        <h4>Question {{ index + 1 }}</h4>
        <fb-question-text v-if="question.type === 'text'" :question="question"></fb-question-text>
    </li>
</ul>
```

As you can see, I am trying to render the fb-question-text component if the question.type is of type "text". While the `<li>` elements do render in the page, the component template does not render entirely. Only the first DOM element inside the template is rendered (in this case, the `<label>` element). The input box and `<a>` that are inside the component do not get rendered for some reason. When I remove the label, the input box gets rendered but nothing after it.

Can someone tell me what is going on?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Templates must have a single root element.

```
<span>
  <label>Prompt</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="question.prompt">
  <a href="javascript:void" class="fb-remove">Remove</a>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `fb-question-text` is only allowed to have one root element. You need to wrap that in a div.

Answer (score 0):

Add `<div>` around `template` html

```js
Vue.component('fb-question-text', {
    props: ['question'],
    template: '<div><label>Prompt</label><input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="question.prompt"><a href="javascript:void" class="fb-remove">Remove</a></div>'
});

var questionList = new Vue({
    el: '#questions',
    data: {
        questions: [
            {
                type: 'text',
                id: 'question1',
                prompt: ''
            },
            {
                type: 'choice',
                id: 'question2',
                prompt: '',
                choices: [ '' , '' ]
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.11/vue.js"></script>
<ul id="questions">
    <li v-for="(question, index) in questions">
        <h4>Question {{ index + 1 }}</h4>
        <fb-question-text v-if="question.type === 'text'" :question="question"></fb-question-text>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

For a similar question I purpose an other answer :
[Vue js error: Component template should contain exactly one root element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45000510/vue-js-error-component-template-should-contain-exactly-one-root-element/51760686#51760686)

copy paste  here :

if, for any reasons, you don't want to add a wrapper (in my first case it was for `<tr/>` components), you can use a functionnal component.

Instead of having a single `components/MyCompo.vue` you will have few files in a `components/MyCompo` folder :

- `components/MyCompo/index.js`
- `components/MyCompo/File.vue`
- `components/MyCompo/Avatar.vue`

With this structure, the way you call your component won't change.

`components/MyCompo/index.js` file content :

```
import File from './File';
import Avatar from './Avatar';   

const commonSort=(a,b)=>b-a;

export default {
  functional: true,
  name: 'MyCompo',
  props: [ 'someProp', 'plopProp' ],
  render(createElement, context) {
    return [
        createElement( File, { props: Object.assign({light: true, sort: commonSort},context.props) } ),
        createElement( Avatar, { props: Object.assign({light: false, sort: commonSort},context.props) } )
    ]; 
  }
};
```

And if you have some function or data used in both templates, passed them as properties and that's it !

I let you imagine building list of components and so much features with this pattern.