# Vue to render tr array recursively

Tags: vuejs2

I have to create collapsible tree with table data using bootstrap. This look the following way

```
<tr><td>Parent node1</td><td>...</td><td>...</td></tr>
<tr><td>Subparent node1.1</td><td>...</td><td>...</td></tr>
<tr><td>Subsupparent node1.1.1</td><td>...</td><td>...</td></tr>
<tr><td>Subsupparent node1.1.2</td><td>...</td><td>...</td></tr>
<tr><td>Subparent node1.2</td><td>...</td><td>...</td></tr>
<tr><td>Subsupparent node2.1.1</td><td>...</td><td>...</td></tr>
<tr><td>Subsupparent node2.1.2</td><td>...</td><td>...</td></tr>
```

I decided to create Vue component rendering on each level html with own data and collection of children via recursion:

```
<template id="tree-item">            
           <tr :key="currentNode.id">
                <span @click="setExpanded(currentNode)">
                    <div style="display: inline-block;">
                        <span class="treegrid-indent" :style="{width: 15 * level + 'px'}"></span>
                        <span class="treegrid-expander fa" :class="currentNode.isExpanded ?'fa-chevron-down':'fa-chevron-right'">
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    {{level}}  {{currentNode.id}}
                </span>
            </tr>
                <tree-item v-for="item in currentNode.items" :currentNode="item" :level="level+1"> </tree-item>       
</template>
```

But i get Vue error:Component template should contain exactly one root element.
Are there any ways to solve the task?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vue js error: Component template should contain exactly one root element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45000510/vue-js-error-component-template-should-contain-exactly-one-root-element)

Comment: I changed the title - maybe there is another way?

Answer (score 0):

If you can relax your requirements to use a list instead of table then you can try something like this:

```
<div class="folder_container">
  <ul class="no_list no_space">
    <FolderTree :folder="folders" :level="0"/>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And the FolderTree component's template looks like this:

```
<template>
  <li>
    <div>
      <div class="folder_name">{{ folder.name }}</div>
    </div>
    <ul v-if="folder.child && folder.child.length > 0" class="no_list no_space">
      <FolderTree
        v-for="(fold,idx) in folder.child"
        :key="fold.id"
        :folder="fold"
        :level="level + 1"
        :last="1 + idx === folder.child.length"
      />
    </ul>
  </li>
</template>
```

If you need to use a table - then you will have to somehow transform your nested objects into a linear list/array of items. Otherwise you won't be able to overcome the limitation for only 1 root element in templates (unless you use render functions).

Comment: with respect  your code to my table: folder_name must be with data columns too, i don't see it in your component

Comment: That is why I said "if you can relax your requirements". You can place a table with a single row instead of `{{ folder_name}}` but these will be distinct tables for each of your items - so unless you set fixed widths for the table columns the columns will have different width in each table, depending on their text content.