# How to make this simple Vue.js code work for a beginner

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I know this question is a duplicate or whatever, but I really need your help. I'm so new with Vue and this is my first Vue.js code and I just followed what they said in the tutorial so I'm lost on why it's not working.

Can you guys help me with this?

here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>   
</head>

<body>
    <script type="x-template" id="form-template">
        <label>{{inputLabel}} :</label>
        <input type="text" v-model="name" />
      </script>

      <div id="app">
        <h2>{{appName}}</h2>
        <form-component title="This is a form" v-bind:name="userName"></form-component>
      </div>    
</body>
</html>
<script>  
var formComponent = {
  template: '#form-template',
  props: ['title', 'name'],
  data: function() {
    return {
      inputLabel: 'Name'
    }
  }
};

var vue = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    appName: 'Component Demo',
    userName: 'John Doe'
  },
  components: {
    'form-component': formComponent
  }
});

</script>
```

error:

```
[Vue warn]: Error compiling template:

Component template should contain exactly one root element. If you are using v-if on multiple elements, use v-else-if to chain them instead.

1  |  
2  |          <label>{{inputLabel}} :</label>
3  |          <input type="text" v-model="name" />
   |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
4  |        
   |  ^^^^^^

found in

---> <FormComponent>
       <Root>
```

Comment: add a containing element (say, a div) that contains everything inside `<script type="x-template" id="form-template">` ... the error message is quite self explanatory

Comment: Yout html is not valid... its not correctly nested ... look at the starting and ending script tags

Comment: @Mischa - nothing wrong at all with the HTML - oh, wait ... that last script tag!! still, all browsers will accept that, and it is NOT the source of the error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vue js error: Component template should contain exactly one root element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45000510/vue-js-error-component-template-should-contain-exactly-one-root-element)

Comment: `<script type="x-template" id="form-template"><div>`your current content`</div></script>`

Comment: wrap your form-template in a `div` container. as mentioned you need one element on the first level of the template. you have 2 (`label` and `input`)

Answer (score 0):

```
  data: {
    appName: 'Component Demo',
    userName: 'John Doe'
  },
```

here the variable name is userName. but on html part you have used `name`

change this to

```
<input type="text" v-model="userName" />
```

Hope this solves the issue

Comment: I'll try this one;)