# How to fix "multiple root element" v-for error

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm new to Vue.js and I'm still learning it. I bumped into this error which I don't know how to solve.

Here is my simple script:

```html
<template>
  <div v-for="item in array" :key="item.id">
    {{item}}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      array: ['Lion','Bear','Fish','Bird']
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

And here is the error that come up:

```
Cannot use v-for on stateful component root element because it renders multiple elements.

  1  |
  2  |  <div v-for="item in array" :key="item.id">
     |       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  3  |    {{item}}
  4  |  </div>
```

Is there anyone who knows how to fix this error?

Comment: Try wrapping this `v-for`-ed `div` in another container.

Comment: this is because you have no root tag. I am assuming you are using vue2 add a div as root. However at Vue3 it should not be an issue anymore because of Fragments

Comment: @MadsterMIZE Please confirm your Vue version. If you're facing this issue, I don't think it's Vue 3.

Comment: Does this answer your question? Clearly a duplicate of [Vue js error: Component template should contain exactly one root element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45000510/vue-js-error-component-template-should-contain-exactly-one-root-element)

Comment: I removed the vuejs3 tag and added vuejs2 instead. Clearly v2 is what you are using.

Comment: Thanks so much guys, apparently i accidently installed vue2 for the project instead of vue3. and apparently i can't find simpler thread for this error and still made beginner like me confuse. thanks for the answer it is helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try also renaming variable from `array` to `animalNames` similar. And remove `id` from loop as there is not `id` element exist, instead you can use `index`

```html
<template>
  <div>
   <div v-for="item,index in array" :key="index">
      {{item}}
   </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: "remove id from loop' this what causes the problem

Answer (score 1):

You must have a root tag. Try wrapping your looped div in another div.

```html
<template>
    <div>
      <div v-for="item in array" :key="item.id">
        {{item}}
      </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      array: ['Lion','Bear','Fish','Bird']
    }
  }
}
</script>
```