# Separate login component than handling component Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router, vuejs3

I am trying to code a mini application with Vue.js. I want to display the login page on the first page if the user is not logged in. Else,
if the user logged in, I want to show a dashboard or a landing page.
I tried it with *app.vue*.

I test with a variable that I created. It works, but when I log in, I can't get access to any other page. Is there a solution to separate the login page from the landing page?

File *App.vue*:

```html
<template>
  <div v-if="mvar" id="app">
    <div>
      <Header />
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <Sidebar />
          <Main />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <notifications />
  </div>
  <div v-else id="app">
    <Login />
    <notifications />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import Main from './components/template/TheMain.vue'
  import Header from './components/template/TheHeader.vue'
  import Sidebar from './components/template/TheSidebarMenu.vue'
  // import Login from "./modules/authentication/AuthLogin.vue";
  export default {
    name: 'App',
    components: {
      Main,
      Header,
      Sidebar,
      // Login,
    },
    data() {
      return {
        mvar: myVar,
      }
    },
  }
</script>
```

Comment: If your app has several pages (login, dashboard etc.), you should use vue-router https://router.vuejs.org/guide/ . Router is used to match url and component.  
Ex: Component Login match to url : "/login" and so on.
After that you can add navigation guard that allow to redirect or cancel navigation depending on conditions (if user is authenticated for instance) 
 some doc https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html

Comment: @kissu Because it's Vue 3, just with Option API. If it was Vue 2, you wouldn't be able to put two `div`s in `template`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45000510/vue-js-error-component-template-should-contain-exactly-one-root-element

Comment: What is meant by the title? It seems incomprehensible.